# If direct "new" makes code coupled, does it apply when I use factory too?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

so basically the wrong code:

```
abstract class Wallet
{
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }
}

class PaypalWallet extends Wallet {}
class CreditcardWallet extends Wallet {}
class VisaWallet extends Wallet {}

class Person
{
    private $wallet;

    public function __construct($walletType, $amount)
    {
        $walletType = 'Wallet'.$walletType;
        $this->wallet = new $walletType($amount);
    }
}

$person1 = new Person('Paypal', 1000);
$person2 = new Person('Creditcard', 2000);
$person3 = new Person('Visa', 3000);
```

lets say I have a factory, so:

```
class Person
{
    private $wallet;

    public function __construct($walletType, $amount)
    {
        $walletType = 'Wallet'.$walletType;
        $this->wallet = \Factory::create($walletType, $amount);
    }
}
```

of course `Factory::create` can be configured to create different class.
This way I still feel it smelly, because `$amount` might doesnt belong to the `Person`, moreover this way it feels like a "fake" DI.
Another refactor:

```
class Person
{
    private $wallet;

    public function __construct(Walett $wallet)
    {
        $this->wallet = $walett;
    }
}

$wallet1 = new PaypalWallet(1000);
$wallet2 = new PaypalWallet(2000);
$wallet3 = new PaypalWallet(3000);
$person1 = new Person($wallet1);
$person2 = new Person($wallet2);
$person3 = new Person($wallet3);
```

this seems to be a pure DI and OOP sollution - but also seems to break the encapsulation. This way, wallet is created outside of the person - but it totally belongs to him! It looks like `$person` and `$walet` are on the same level, while Person should create and own the Wallet... or not? Which way is it good?

Comment: Conceptually, does anything else besides a `Person` interact with your `Wallet` objects?

Comment: @WillardSolutions, nope, nothing.

Comment: OOP principles shouldn't get in the way of readable, common-sense code. Is a `Wallet`an essential component of a `Person` in your app? If not, you probably shouldn't pass wallet-related data through the `Person` constructor. Short answer- there's no "best" way to do this - its highly contingent on your specific use case.

Comment: indeed. I rather choose my last example, no perfect solution, but then we wont hurt the "currier" antipattern. This enlighted me: https://r.je/oop-courier-anti-pattern.html